# Get property from mapped click event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to be able to access a mapped items ID. so inside the map, I have a link button that has an onClick event. How can I access that specific items ID when it is clicked?

```
idTest(){
    console.log('id:', item.id);
}

this.dataTest = this.state.data.map((item, key) => 

    <div key={item.Id}>
        <div><p>{item.id}</p></div>
        <Link to='/package_summary' onClick={this.idTest}>Click</Link>
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing `this.idTest`, use anynomous function and pass `item.id` as a param of `this.idTest`:

```
<Link to='/package_summary' onClick={() => this.idTest(item.id)}>Click</Link>
```

Comment: this stops the e.preventDefault() i had on this.idTest, so now i cant see the error it throws.